# How PriorityQueue work when I do poll?

Tags: java, priority-queue

I have a predefined class named Pair with a key and a value. I store them in PriorityQueue based on the natural order of value of each Pair. When I change value of one of the Pair and then dequeue, what I expect did not happen. The test code is below. Please help. I feel confused!

```java
import java.util.*;
public class Test {
  static class Pair {
      int key;
      int value;
      Pair (int key, int value) {
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
      }
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
      PriorityQueue<Pair> pq = new PriorityQueue<Pair>(3, new Comparator<Pair>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Pair p1, Pair p2) {
            return p1.value - p2.value;
        }
    });
    Pair p1 = new Pair(1, 31);
    Pair p2 = new Pair(2, 32);
    Pair p3 = new Pair(3, 33);
    pq.offer(p1);
    pq.offer(p2);
    pq.offer(p3);
    p2.value = 31;
    p1.value = 32;
    Pair p0 = pq.poll(); // It shows the reference p0 is p1 not expected p2. 
                        // And what remain in pq are p2 with 31 and p3 with 33
  }
}
```

I know that PriorityQueue will sort the item when polling. It seems like the PriorityQueue in my example didn't work.

Comment: Why do you expect p2?

Comment: "I know that PriorityQueue will sort the item when polling" <- Do you really? The JavaDoc says nothing like that for the method poll and to me it looks the poll method simple gets and returns the current object at index 0 and then sorts the queue _after_ that.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I thought that the `value`(used for compare function) of p2 is the minimum among those three `Pair`s so that `PriorityQueue` should poll the `Pair` with the minimum `value`, which is p2.

Comment: @911DidBush Yes, you are right. Vague concepts about how `PriorityQueue` poll was in my mind so I review the source code in JDK 7 which I'm using. The `poll` function gets the object at index 0 and then maintains the heap according to the default `Comparator` or the predefined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you have any data structure such as a Hash Map/Set, TreeMap/Set or a sorted queue like PriorityQueue, if you mutate one of the elements (in particular a field used for hashCode/equals/compareTo depending on what methods(s) are used), the data structure doesn't know to re-arrange itself, instead what you are doing is corrupting the data structure so it won't work as expected.

In short, you can't mutate the key fields of an object in a data structure and expect it to behave in a reliable manner.

Comment: Thank you for your time! I got it now. If I want to update the priority of certain object, I need to remove it from `PriorityQueue`, change key and then re-insert it, or write a heap by myself.

Comment: @WalterWang yes, that what you need to do with many data structures (except arrays and Lists)